# Searching a TreeView

Tags: python, treeview, pyqt5

I am working on a project and am using a treeview. I have done lots of searching and all ive found to my answer is to itterate through the whole treeview but not even how to do it, so my question is how do i search a treeview for an item that contains an input string. The idea will be to have an entry box and have users type something in there, when they press search items that contain what the user has input is shown. I'm not sure if i could do this in the treeview or if it will have to go into a listview. I'm on windows 7 pyqt5 python 3.5

```
self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralWidget)
self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.treeView.setObjectName("treeView")
self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.treeView)
self.file_model=QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
self.file_model.setRootPath('C:\My Stuff\Movies')
self.treeView.setModel(self.file_model)
self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.file_model.index('C:\My Stuff\Movies'))
self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
self.treeView.hideColumn(1)
self.treeView.hideColumn(2)
self.treeView.hideColumn(3)
```

Comment: Also if anyone knows how to sort a treeview that would be helpful

Comment: You want to search the model not the view I think. Once you have found the index in the model you can then select that index on the view.

Comment: I think you need to use a QSortFilterProxyModel between your view and model. That is what I have used for tables and I think it is the same for trees.

Comment: @BarryScott thanks for the help. how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an outline of the solution.

You may find the code I wrote for SCM Workbench useful for reference:

https://github.com/barry-scott/scm-workbench/blob/master/Source/Scm/wb_scm_table_model.py

In my app the function indexFromBookmark() I think is close to what you
want.

To start you need the root of the tree. You get that item with self.invisibleRootItem().

You can ask two interesting things of the item. Its name from item.text() and its children by calling item.child( row ) where the row starts from 0.

When the item of interest is found you can turn the item into an index using indexFromItem(). You need an index to set the selection in the tree for example.

With file names I guess you split on '\' and each items text() is the path part.